# Problema de timing na execução do código

Tags: javascript, node.js

Fala pessoal, fiz um pequeno script pra redimensionar umas imagens, salvar localmente e criar um zip com cada uma delas, no entanto, quando o programa vai criar o zip, a imagem ainda não terminou de ser processada e não foi salva ainda, aí quando vai zipar, ele nao encontra a imagem e traz um erro.

libs:

- JIMP (para edição de imagens)
- AdmZip (para zipar imagens)

```
const jimp = require("jimp")
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

const imgs = [img1, img2, img3] // array com imagens

//tratando cada uma das imagens

for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length ; i++){ 
    let name = imgs[i].match(/[^\/]*$/)
    jimp.read(imgs[i], (err, imgs) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        imgs    
                .resize(jimp.AUTO,720)
                .quality(80)
                .write(`./images/${name}.jpg`); 
    })

//zipando a imagem
   
        let zip = new AdmZip();
        zip.addLocalFile(`./images/${name}.jpg`); <<< ERRO POIS A IMAGEM NÃO FOI ENCONTRADA PQ AINDA TÁ SENDO PROCESSADA PELO BLOCO ACIMA
         zip.writeZip(/*target file name*/`./images/${name}.zip`);
   
   
   
}
```

Eu até fiz funcionar botando um `setinterval` pra esperar a imagem acabar de ser salva pra o zip encontrar a imagem:

```
    setInterval(()=>{
        let zip = new AdmZip();
        zip.addLocalFile(`./images/${name}.jpg`);
         zip.writeZip(/*target file name*/`./images/${name}.zip`);
    },5000)
```

mas acredito que haja uma forma melhor de resolver, sem precisar fazer essa gambiarra do setinterval. Vocês podem me ajudar?

Comment: opa, adicionei lá, obrigado pela dica!!!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que está faltando usar as Promises para aguardar o retorno. Olhando a documentação da biblioteca eu achei isso aqui.

[Documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)

Example usage (Promise will never resolve if callback is passed):

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');
// open a file called "lenna.png"
Jimp.read('lenna.png', (err, lenna) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  lenna
    .resize(256, 256) // resize
    .quality(60) // set JPEG quality
    .greyscale() // set greyscale
    .write('lena-small-bw.jpg'); // save
});
```

Using promises:

```
Jimp.read('lenna.png')
  .then(lenna => {
    return lenna
      .resize(256, 256) // resize
      .quality(60) // set JPEG quality
      .greyscale() // set greyscale
      .write('lena-small-bw.jpg'); // save
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Espero que ajude :D